# JavaScript string manipulation

Tags: javascript, string

I am trying to create a function that builds a string made up of the characters of two given strings.

The function has 3 arguments:

1. `searchString` - a String that is scanned character by character to
   identify the position of `newCharacter`
2. `originalString` - a string the same length as *searchString*
3. `newCharacter` - a 1 character string.

The function should return a new string that contains `newCharacter` in the same positions as in `searchString` otherwise the characters at the corresponding positions of the `originalString`.

Example:

```
searchString = data, 
originalString = bcde 
newCharacter = a
```

The function would return `"bada"`.

Comment: Can you provide sample input and output of what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Your description is very confusing. For start, what is `targetString`? Another argument?

Comment: Sure. Let me give it a go and I'll try to explain.

Comment: Could you provide a sample with inputs an an expected result?

Comment: Okay - updated the question with some examples and tried to clarify in more depth what I'm struggling with. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
var rossFn = function (searchString, originalString, newCharacter) {
    var initialValue = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < searchString.length; i++) {
        if (searchString.charAt(i) === newCharacter) {
            initialValue += newCharacter;
        } else {
            initialValue += originalString.charAt(i);
        }
    }
    return initialValue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I'm sorry that it doesn't make much sense. I have elaborated a little on the initial question. You guys clearly have superior brains :)

Comment: Ah, thanks a lot! You're a genius. it works perfectly. Haha. I'm amazed that you were able to figure that out from my gibberish.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this:

```
function manipulateString(searchString, originalString, newCharacter)
{
    //convert strings to array
    searchString = searchString.split(''); 
    originalString = originalString.split(''); 
    //find indices in the search string where new character occurs
    var matchingIndicesInSearchString = searchString.reduce(function(a, e, i) {
        if (e === newCharacter)
            a.push(i);
        return a;
    }, []);  

    matchingIndicesInSearchString.forEach(function (value, index, array) 
    {  //replace characters in the original string with the new character at the right indices
       originalString.splice(value,1, newCharacter);
    });
    //convert array back to string 
    return originalString.toString().replace(/,/g,'');  
}
```

It works. Please use like so:

```
var searchString   = 'data', 
    originalString = 'bcde', 
    newCharacter   = 'a';

manipulateString(searchString, originalString, newCharacter); //outputs 'bada'
```